# Css hover doesn't take effect on asp button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i'm adding some css to my school project and hover effect does not work on asp:button. I linked css class like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css"/>
```

and then button in .aspx site:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="txt" CssClass="glow-on-hover"/>
```

The button is styled, but there is no effect when clicking on, or when i'm moving mouse over it. However it does work when i use it on html button like this. How can i make this work on asp:button?

```css
.glow-on-hover {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

    .glow-on-hover:before {
        content: '';
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: -2px;
        background-size: 400%;
        z-index: -1;
        filter: blur(5px);
        width: calc(100% + 4px);
        height: calc(100% + 4px);
        animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:active {
        color: #000
    }

        .glow-on-hover:active:after {
            background: transparent;
        }

    .glow-on-hover:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:after {
        z-index: -1;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #111;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

@keyframes glowing {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 400% 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="glow-on-hover" type="button">txt</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I've just put it in js fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/definaly/pdzjc7g9/) and it seems to work just fine

Comment: Well as i said, it does work on html button, but doesn't take any effect on that asp:button i mentioned earlier.

Comment: An asp button is `<input type=submit>`, not `<button>`. Change it to a LinkButton.

Comment: @VDWWD it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psuedo selectors `:before` and `:after` can't be used on an `<input type="submit" />` because an `<input>` can't contain any children.

Can you change your code to render a `<button>` rather than an `<input>`.